# Error setting Color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new with three.js. Basically I want to make something like a  chessboard. I got this:

```
for( x=-30; x<=50;x=x+10){
        for( y=-30; y<=20;y=y+10 ){
            var TileGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5,5);
            var TileMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
            var Tile = new THREE.Mesh(TileGeometry,TileMaterial);
            //tile.receiveShadow = true
            Tile.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
            Tile.position.x = x;
            Tile.position.y = 0;
            Tile.position.z = y;
            Tile.castShadow=true;
            scene.add(Tile);
            //whiteTile.material.color.setHex(0x000000);
            tiles.push(Tile);
        }
    }


    for(var tile in tiles){
        if(count%2==0){
            tile.material.color.setHex(0x000000);
            }
        else{
            tile.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);
            }
        count++;
    }
```

Tiles are correctly positioned. The problem is when setting the color.
I'm getting:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined`

Comment: you could also use a shader http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/checker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for ... in` loops iterate the *keys* of an object so `tile` is actually the *index* not the object within the array, use a normal `for` loop or `forEach`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
  tiles[i].material.color.setHex(i % 2 ? 0xffffff : 0);
```

[Read more about `for ... in` loops on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)