# How to create arrays of cube elements to create a chessboard in 3.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make two arrays to create black and white alternating squares in an 8x8 grid to form a chessboard in Three.js. Where do I begin? I can create basic geometries and have, but don't want to, manually create the board using 64 individual components. I also would like each cube to be named after the corresponding position (eg. a1, a2, a3 etc).

Currently I have this:

```
var boardGeometryArray = [];
var boardMaterialBlackArray = [];
var boardMaterialWhiteArray = [];
var boardBlackArray = [];
var boardWhiteArray = [];

var boardBlack = 4;
for (var br = -0; br<boardBlack; br++){

        boardGeometryArray.push ( new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,0,5));
        boardMaterialBlackArray.push ( new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color : 0x000000}));
        boardBlackArray.push ( new THREE.Mesh(boardGeometryArray[br],boardMaterialBlackArray[br]))
        boardBlackArray[br].position.z = 5.0;
        boardBlackArray[br].position.x = br*10;
        scene.add(boardBlackArray[br]);
}

var boardWhite = 4;
for (var bc = 0; bc<boardWhite; bc++){

        boardGeometryArray.push ( new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,0,5));
        boardMaterialWhiteArray.push ( new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color : 0xffffff}));
        boardWhiteArray.push ( new THREE.Mesh(boardGeometryArray[bc],boardMaterialWhiteArray[bc]))
        boardWhiteArray[bc].position.z = 5;
        boardWhiteArray[bc].position.x = (bc*10)+5;
        scene.add(boardWhiteArray[bc]);
}
```

and I'm chipping away at it but a nudge in the right direction will help as it currently creates a row of alternating colours but not an 8x8 board.

Comment: If anyone can input with how to alternate the colours for one array instead of two that would also be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30949085/4045502)

Comment: That doesn't really help.